# What does EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing setting do in C# .NET windows forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a per-monitor DPI aware application using C# .NET with regular windows forms (not WPF).

I understand the concept of opting into per-monitor DPI support, and have done this in the manifest:

```
<!-- Indicates that the application is DPI-aware and will not be automatically scaled by Windows at higher
   DPIs. Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications are automatically DPI-aware and do not need 
   to opt in. Windows Forms applications targeting .NET Framework 4.6 that opt into this setting, should 
   also set the 'EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing' setting to 'true' in their app.config. -->

<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">True/PM</dpiAware>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

When I opt into that, my application does not change its *pixel* size at all when it is dragged from a 96DPI monitor (my default monitor) onto a 144DPI monitor (i.e. the application is pixel-for-pixel identical on both monitors, save for very slight differences in the minimize-maximize-close glyphs). Hence the application is very small and the text is hard to read on the 144DPI monitor.

It seems that the `EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing` setting has no effect, as my app displays in exactly the same way whether this setting is true or false, unless I have done something wrong in my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Can anybody shed light on what this option does?

Is it part of the solution for writing a C# windows form application which will automatically resize itself when dragged from a 96DPI monitor onto a 144DPI monitor? (by automatic I mean, without me writing code to iterate over all the controls and set a custom scale factor).

I have done many hours of research into this problem and don't have a clear answer myself yet.

It seems that if I opt into per-monitor DPI awareness then I **must** hanldle the `WM_DPICHANGED` myself in order to do something. If that is the answer, so be it, but I really feel like I have missed some built in way of doing things.

Comment: It enables bug fixes that were made in .NET releases since 4.5 that corrected DPI problems in various controls.  Best example is the NumericUpDown control, the up/down arrows were too narrow on a high DPI screen.  Win8.1's per-monitor DPI feature is a completely different kettle of fish and you get no help at all.  You must override WndProc() so you can see the WM_DPICHANGED message. rescaling the window is entirely your own burden.  Only easy to do in WPF, in Winforms you could hack it by changing the form's Font property.  Doesn't always turn out well, easy to check in the designer.

Comment: Thanks Hans. My next question would then be can I target xp<->windows 10 using WPF? Perhaps it is time for me to learn a new technology... I would just make a UWP app if I didn't need to support windows xp.

Comment: What burns me up the most is that C# obviously has the ability to automatically resize the form, since it does so at program start if the primary monitor is selected as a high DPI monitor. Seems like they could easily fix it up to support per-monitor mode properly, but I guess they are busy with UWP and WPF and all the other myriad of technologies they have...

Comment: Starting with .NET Framework 4.7 and the Windows 10 Creators Update, you can specify per-monitor DPI awareness for Windows Forms applications by adding a `DpiAwareness` key in the app.config file. Details on how to do this can be found on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt799789(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

"dpiAware = true" means application should handle the DPI change, otherwise Windows OS will scale the form/font for you. This is my understanding.

Comment: Yes, you are not incorrect, but this wasn't the question. I was asking about `EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `appSettings` tag with `System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection`, which is the right [configuration section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/winforms/windows-forms-add-configuration-element).

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    </startup>

    <System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
        <add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="true" />
    </System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
</configuration>
```

If you are enabling `Hi DPI Support` for [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#appmanifest), then include the `dpiAwareness` tag for Win10 and above:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true/pm</dpiAware>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```